# SaltStack check if grain exists in Jinja file

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm using SaltStack to manage my infra. Machines are hosted in different DCs, so they also have slightly different network setup.
Currently, I'm running into the following issue:

```
Comment: Unable to manage file: Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'macaddress'; line 9
              
              ---
              [...]
                ethernets:
                  {{ grains['interface_context'] }}:
                    dhcp4: {{ grains['dhcp4'] }}
                    dhcp6: {{ grains['dhcp6'] }}
                    addresses: [{{ grains['ipv4'] }}, "{{ grains['ipv6'] }}"]
                    {% if grains['macaddress'] %}    <======================
                    match:
                        macaddress: {{ grains['macaddress'] }}
                    {% endif %}
                    routes:
                      - to: default
              [...]
              ---
```

As the message indicates, the grain "macaddress" is missing, which I can confirm, it's not set for this minion. But What I do not understand is how I can simply check if this variable/grain exists at all within a jinja template?
I wouldn't expect this error to come up, as I actually wanted to catch it with the if statement.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get` to return `None` instead of raising:

```
{% if grains.get('macaddress') is not none %}
```

Or if you want to treat "empty" values the same:

```
{% if not grains.get('macaddress') %}
```